# Geth get deployed contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-invocation, nodejs

I am new to the blockchain and up until now I have managed to deploy contracts and transfer ether through both geth console and node code... I am now trying to figure out how to get the contract that I already deployed and interact with it through both Geth and javascript... I will appreciate any help.

thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of the main steps you need.  You need the ABI (from when you compiled the contract) and the address you deployed to.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example-50

```
// contract abi
var abi = [{
     name: 'myConstantMethod',
     type: 'function',
     constant: true,
     inputs: [{ name: 'a', type: 'string' }],
     outputs: [{name: 'd', type: 'string' }]
}, {
     name: 'myStateChangingMethod',
     type: 'function',
     constant: false,
     inputs: [{ name: 'a', type: 'string' }, { name: 'b', type: 'int' }],
     outputs: []
}, {
     name: 'myEvent',
     type: 'event',
     inputs: [{name: 'a', type: 'int', indexed: true},{name: 'b', type: 'bool', indexed: false}]
}];

// creation of contract object
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

// initiate contract for an address
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0xc4abd0339eb8d57087278718986382264244252f');

// call constant function
var result = myContractInstance.myConstantMethod('myParam');
console.log(result) // '0x25434534534'
```